# How to easily add large number of string resources(like list of countries) to android? (applicable to any other web/mobile language too)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web

Typical scenario in an app where you want to provide options for autocomplete. You don't want to enter each element and add tags manually.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to provide an autocomplete list for a list of all countries.

-Get the list of countries online.

-Paste them in a column in excel.(say column B)

-On the first row on the column A(col to the left of ur countries column) put the start tag ( in the case of android), on the right column put the end tag().

-Now,copy  to all the cells in column A to correspond to a country in col B.
-Do the same for the closing tags(Column C ).

-Put the following formula on Column D Row1 "=TRIM($A1)&TRIM($B1)&TRIM($C1)".

-Copy-paste the formula to all the cells in col D corresponding to each cell in ColB(Number of countries).

-You, now have a list of all countries with tags in column D.

-Just copy paste this to the Strings array in your strings.xml file.

This method is probably used quite commonly by seasoned programmers, but its something not typically taught in books. Hope this saves people time.
Cheers!

Comment: Do you planning to answer your own question?

Comment: Yea...it's  a pretty neat feature  of stack overflow....just wanted to share  knowledge.